# iOS: How do I set the Identifier and Version fields in a crash log?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

When I look at an iOS crash log, I see the following two fields near the head of the crash log:

```
Identifier:      MyCoolApp
Version:         ??? (???)
```

I've already tried setting the following in MyCoolApp-Info.plist

```
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>NF_201104011216</string>
```

and

```
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.9.0.201104011216</string>
```

and

```
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.9.0</string>
```

but to no avail so far. My crash logs are always unchanged despite changing those fields in the plist file.

The following article discusses these but it doesn't say how they are used (if at all) in the crash dump file: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with crash reporter.. this cannot be set.  There is a bit of a sloppy work around though, see related question:

[iPhone crash logs say "Version: ???"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112683/iphone-crash-logs-say-version)

Comment: That's perfect, that's even better than a version number. As long as I have a way of matching the crash log to a build and can then add the matching debug symbols, I'm all set.